# hyperfootnotes=false removes link but superscripts still show up at bottom of table

Tags: tables, hyperref, footnotes

I want to remove the hyperlinks to the footnotes associated with a table in my document.  When I use `\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}`, the hyperlinking action is indeed removed; however, the superscripts still show up (with no link) at the bottom of my table.  Here is screenshot of what I'm talking about, and the code that produces it:

[image: Footnote table example]

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}  
\linespread{1.8}  
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}                                                   
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{c p{2cm} p{2cm} c c c} & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Odds Ratio$^a$} \\ 
\cline{4-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1$^b$} & \centering Column 2 & \centering Column 3 & 0.25 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\cline{1-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\centering Content} & \centering 70 & \centering\multirow{2}{*}{$A^c$} & Numbers & Numbers & Numbers \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & & (Numbers) & (Numbers) & (Numbers) \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & \centering \multirow{2}{*}{$B^c$} & Numbers & Numbers & Numbers \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & & (Numbers) & (Numbers) & (Numbers) \\
\footnote{~Footnote 1}
\footnote{~Footnote 2}
\footnote{~Footnote 3}
\end{tabular}  
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

What I'm referring to are the italic a, b and c within the table in the lower left corner, above where the footnotes start - I don't want those there.

Also, I want to say that I'm not interested in using `\sidewaystable` (I don't want the table rotated), if that somehow comes up.

Comment: What about actually putting the `\footnote` command where you actually want them, i.e. `\multicolumn{3}{c}{Odds Ratio\footnote{Footnote 1}}` instead of `\multicolumn{3}{c}{Odds Ratio$^a$}` or `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1\footnote{Footnote 2}}` instead of `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1$^b$}`. Of course, then you do not have to call `\footnote{~Footnote 1}` again at the end of the table.

Comment: Ah, so easy.  I didn't think it mattered if I put them at the end, but obviously that's what was causing the error!  Thank you!  If you write this up as the answer I'll select it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use the footnote command where you actually want the footnote to appear.
LaTeX places them exactly where `\footnote{bar}` is used.

Then, of course, there is no need to place `\footnote{foo}` at the end of the table.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{article}  
\linespread{1.8}  
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}                                                   
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{c p{2cm} p{2cm} c c c} & & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Odds Ratio\footnote{Footnote 1}} \\ 
\cline{4-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1\footnote{Footnote 2}} & \centering Column 2 & \centering Column 3 & 0.25 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\cline{1-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\centering Content} & \centering 70 & \centering\multirow{2}{*}{$A$\footnote{Footnote 3}} & Numbers & Numbers & Numbers \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & & (Numbers) & (Numbers) & (Numbers) \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & \centering \multirow{2}{*}{{$B$\footnote{Footnote 3}} & Numbers & Numbers & Numbers \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & & (Numbers) & (Numbers) & (Numbers) \\
\end{tabular}  
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: And, just because it was relevant to my case where I was using the same superscript multiple times, see http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&p=24161 (see the second solution, for cases with lettered superscripts). If you use \footnote{Footnote 3} twice (as in the solution), it will give them each separate superscripts (but with the same footnote).